# Wordpress Category url redirects to subdomain

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

I've a wordpress category - `peer`. And I've set my permalink settings so that category url is - `http://example.com/peer` (no `/category/` in the url).

Problem is I also have a subdirectory called `peer` at the root of Wordpress installation and I've setup a subdomain `peer.example.com` which will point to this sub directory.

When I try to access `http://example.com/peer` it will be redirected to subdomain `http://peer.example.com`. How do I avoid this?

**How do I make the url `http://example.com/peer` point to the wordpress category page instead of sub directory/sub domain?**

I'm using Apache on Cent OS. I also have access to cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Apache directs your traffic to the directory "peer" before WordPress is even loaded. You have two choices here. Either you edit the .htaccess to redirect the user to WordPress or you simply change the name of the directory and point the "peer.example.com" subdomain to that directory instead.